# box.delete[1] not working properly ! Box over box - Gap Script - Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to improve this script which marks the Gaps. I put a function box.delete[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecf93.jpg) so that the rectangle fades as prices make new highs on the gap low but it continue to draws new rectangles. When prices make a new high, new rectangles are drawn every 5 minutes. Can you help me ?

[Box over box when price touched it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecf93.jpg)

[Not affected when price don't touch the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0GJb.jpg)

And if i change the UT it work fine, it's only on the 5min because i was in 5min when it touch the low

[Not affected in 2min or 15min etc, only in 5min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri8h8.jpg)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Asch-

//@version=5
indicator(title='GAP DETECTOR fini DAX DJI', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500, max_lines_count = 500)


var i = input.int(450, "Length ", minval = 1)


///////////// Make a loop to refresh the indicator ? Word when i refresh the indicator or change the UT

length = bar_index > 500 ? i : na

//// not understand useless ?
passed_length = bar_index == 0 ? 500 : length
///// 

width = input.int(2, options=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

gap_start = high[length]
gap_end = low[length - 1]


gap_bull = false
gap_bear = false

inf_gap = 0.0
sup_gap = 0.0

if barstate.islast

    for j = 1 to length by 1
        gap_bull := false
        gap_bear = false
        
        inf_gap := 0.0
        sup_gap := 0.0

        if high[j] < low[j - 1]  //bull gap
            gap_start := high[j]
            gap_end := low[j - 1]
            gap_bull := true
            inf_gap := gap_start
            sup_gap := gap_end
            for i = j - 1 to 0 by 1
                sup_gap := math.min(sup_gap, low[i])
                sup_gap
            if (sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 10) < 5  // only gap > 5 pips are considered
                gap_bull := false
                gap_bull

        if low[j] > high[j - 1]  //bear gap
            gap_start := low[j]
            gap_end := high[j - 1]
            gap_bear := true
            inf_gap := gap_end
            sup_gap := gap_start
            for i = j - 1 to 0 by 1
                inf_gap := math.max(inf_gap, high[i])
                inf_gap
            if (sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 10) < 5  // only gap > 5 pips are considered
                gap_bear := false
                gap_bear
/////////////////////////WORK 
        if gap_bull


            label_bull = label.new(bar_index[j], na, 'Bull gap: ' + str.tostring((sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) + ' pips\n' + '[' + str.tostring(inf_gap) + ' ; ' + str.tostring(sup_gap) + ']', color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)  
//label.delete(label_bull[1])

            
            boxbull = box.new(left=bar_index[j], top=sup_gap, right=bar_index + 100, bottom=inf_gap, border_width=2)
            box.set_border_color(boxbull, color=color.new(color.green, 50))
            box.set_border_width(boxbull, 1)
            box.set_bgcolor(boxbull, color.new(color.green, 70))
            box.delete(boxbull[1])


        if gap_bear
        
            boxbear = box.new(left=bar_index[j], top=sup_gap, right=bar_index + 100, bottom=inf_gap, border_width=2)
            box.set_border_color(boxbear, color=color.new(color.red, 50))
            box.set_border_width(boxbear, 1)
            box.set_bgcolor(boxbear, color.new(color.red, 70))
            box.delete(boxbear[1])
            
            
            label_bear = label.new(bar_index[j], na, 'Bear gap: ' + str.tostring((sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) + ' pips\n' + '[' + str.tostring(inf_gap) + ' ; ' + str.tostring(sup_gap) + ']', color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
            //label.delete(label_bear[1])
           
//line.delete(line_bear_sup[1])
```

Thank you !

EDIT :

Array Script

```
//@version=5
indicator('Loop through arrays test')

arr = array.new_int(0)

array.push(arr, 1)
array.push(arr, 2)
array.push(arr, 3)
array.push(arr, 4)
array.push(arr, 5)

lab = ''
for i = 0 to array.size(arr) - 1 by 1
    lab += str.tostring(array.get(arr, array.size(arr) - 1 - i)) + ' '
    lab

l = label.new(bar_index, close, lab)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating boxes inside `for loop`.
Command `box.delete(boxbear[1])` actually accessing last box object created inside loop on the previous bar.

If inside `for j = 1 to length by 1`  the `gap_bull` condition will be `true` every time, then `boxbear = box.new()` will be create `length` amount of boxes for that bar, where calculation occured. And `box.delete(boxbear[1])` will delete the last one from the loop of the previous bar, because [] is the historical operator for the series, and the series consists from 1 value for every bar.
You can try to solve your issue with arrays of boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It doesn't seem so simple, is it easier to make the boxes transparent instead of removing them ? I found a script to do a countdown with array but I don't see how to proceed, it can give me a reverse count

Comment: I find this one with array ill look 
https://www.tradingview.com/script/MsW7e2Sw-Customizable-Gap-Finder/